# CSS demora para carregar no resize da janela

Tags: html, jquery, css, materialize

É uma pergunta de iniciante ainda, estou utilizando o framework materialize e estou com um problema que quando diminuo ou aumento a janela alguns elementos demoram para o css carregar, ou as vezes preciso até atualizar a página para carregar o css de um elemento específico. Nesse caso é um ícone que sai de sua posição quando a janela redimensiona. Queria saber se alguém pode me ajudar a evitar isso. Esse é o código do botão login, aonde ele fica

```
<a class="dropdown-button right" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown-login" 
   data-beloworigin="true" id="btn-header">          
        <span id="text-drop">
             Login
        </span>
        <i class="mdi mdi-account right"></i>
        <i class="mdi mdi-menu-down right" id="down-arrow"></i>        
</a>
```

CÓDIGO CSS

```
#btn-header .mdi-account{
    margin-left: 5px !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    float: none !important;
    width: 20px !important;
}
#btn-header .mdi-menu-down{
    margin-left: -5px !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    float: none !important;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua pergunta não é clara. Uma vez que o CSS é carregado na página, ele fica ativo em tempo real... não existe isso de "carregar o CSS" ao redimensionar a tela. Seria bom reformular sua pergunta e explicar melhor o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Eu fiz regras css para diferentes resoluções, o que acontece é que quando chega em determinada resolução justamente quando eu redimensiono a tela algumas propriedades demoram para carregar. No caso as propriedades que foram setadas para aquela resolução específica.

Comment: Se possível mostre **imagens do erro** e de como deveria ficar do jeito certo. Coloque tb o CSS completo com as `@medias` que fez etc.